# How can I set the 'topic' property in FCM?

Tags: android, node.js, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I tried to send an FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) message in Node.js, I encountered an error stating that the 'topic' property is invalid. However, even after reading the official documentation, I couldn't find a solution. How can I set the 'topic' property correctly?

```
const message = {
  data: {
    score: '850',
    time: '2:45'
  },
  notification: {
    title: 'title',
    body: 'body',
    badge: "1",
    sound: "default"
 },
  topic: 'topic'
};

  admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, message, option)
  .then(pushResponse => {
    return { text: token };
  })
  .catch(error => {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error.message, error);
  });
```

error text:
`Exception from a finished function: Error: Messaging payload contains an invalid "topic" property. Valid properties are "data" and "notification".`

I tried the following method, but it didn't work.

```
getMessaging().send(message)
  .then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
```

error text:
`Exception from a finished function: ReferenceError: getMessaging is not defined`

```
  admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic,message,option)
  .then(pushResponse => {
    return { text: token };
  })
  .catch(error => {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error.message, error);
  });
```

I was able to send the FCM, but the Flutter app crashed immediately after receiving the FCM.

Comment: In the example at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message, when they specify a topic the message they sent contained data but no notification.  What happens if you leave the notification field off?  (or leave the data field off?)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I did comment out the 'notification' part, but the same error still occurs.

Comment: ` Exception from a finished function: Error: Messaging payload contains an invalid "topic" property. Valid properties are "data" and "notification".`

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this, you can try it

```
{
  "notification": {
  "title": "title notification",
  "body": "content"
  },
  "to": "/topics/name_of_topic",
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried sending it as you suggested, but the error still occurs.

`
const message = {
  data: {
    score: '850',
    time: '2:45'
  },
  notification: {
    title: 'title',
    body: 'body',
    badge: "1",
    sound: "default"
 },
  topic: 'topic/topic_name'
};
`